# Why does this Rust 2018 code compile with `cargo build` but not using rustc?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

When compiling this snippet below using cargo build, the borrow checker seems fine but when using rustc I get the error

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `char_counts` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:14:17
   |
10 |         let count = char_counts.get(&char);
   |                     ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
14 |                 char_counts.insert(char, rem);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
19 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

Any ideas why this happens?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn anagram(word: &str, another_word: &str) -> i32 {
    let mut char_counts = HashMap::new();
    for char in word.chars() {
        let count = char_counts.entry(char).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
    }
    for char in another_word.chars() {
        let count = char_counts.get(&char);
        if let Some(val) = count {
            let rem = val - 1;
            if rem > 0 {
                char_counts.insert(char, rem);
            } else {
                char_counts.remove(&char);
            }
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", char_counts);
    return char_counts.keys().len() as i32;
}
```

`cargo --version` and `rustc --version` commands both output `1.33`

Comment: What are the outputs of `rustc --version` and `cargo --version`?

Comment: both commandas output `1.33`

Comment: I observe the same behaviour (Linux, 1.33.0 for `rustc`). Curiously, if I do `rustc --edition 2018 main.rs` it compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function will compile fine if you have [non-lexical lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html) enabled and won't compile without them. The 2018 edition enables them by default. Perhaps you have `edition = "2018"` in your `Cargo.toml`, but are not passing it as parameter when using rustc directly?